# несколько одинаковых ng-reapet

Tags: javascript, angularjs

у меня появилась проблема с выводом нескольких одинаковых элементов с директивой ng-reapet.
У меня в scope находиться массив c hex кодом цветов, и мне его надо выводить несколько раз с помощью ng-reapet:

```
<div ng-repeat="color in color_code" ng-style="{'background-color' : color}" style='width: 50px; height: 50px'>
</div>
```

При выводе большого количества подобных элементов вылетает ошибка. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение, выглядит так:

```
<div ng-repeat="color in color_code track by $index" ng-style="{'background-color' : color}" style='width: 50px; height: 50px'>
                </div>
```

Добавил `track by $index` в конец ng-reapet и все заработало.